# PHP how to map importer fields to csv first row fields?

Tags: php, data-import

I am importing rims from an csv file to a webshop project. nothing for sell, just a personal project for learning how importers work.
I am trying to map my $EANColumn variable to the first row field name in my csv.

So currently i have a csv with the following fields :

EAN;Brand;...and-more-comming

---

1234-WB;WheelBrand...and-more-comming

---

5678-BW;BrandWheel...and-more-comming

---

At the moment in my importer, it works when i map:

```
$EANColumn     = str_replace('’', '', $importData_arr["EAN"]);
```

And inserting it to my database through an array :

```
foreach($importData_arr as $importData){
           // var_dump($importData);
            $insertData = array(
                "EAN" =>$EANColumn);
            RimsUpload::insertData($insertData);
```

My complete code for this part is here :

```
if ($request->input('submit') != null ){

      $file = $request->file('file');

      // File Details
      $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
      $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
      $tempPath = $file->getRealPath();
      $fileSize = $file->getSize();
      $mimeType = $file->getMimeType();

      // Valid File Extensions
      $valid_extension = array("csv");

      // 2MB in Bytes
      $maxFileSize = 2097152;

      // Check file extension
      if(in_array(strtolower($extension),$valid_extension)){

        // Check file size
        if($fileSize <= $maxFileSize){

          // File upload location
          $location = 'uploads';

          // Upload file
          $file->move($location,$filename);

          // Import CSV to Database
          $filepath = url($location."/".$filename);

          // Reading file
          $file = fopen($filepath,"r");

          $importData_arr = array();
          $i = 0;

          while (($filedata = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
             $num = count($filedata );

             $EANColumn     = str_replace('’', '', $importData_arr["EAN"]);
             $BrandColumn   = $importData_arr["Brand"];

             // Skip first row (Remove below comment if you want to skip the first row)
             if($i == 0){
                $i++;
                continue;
             }

             for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                $importData_arr[$i][] = $filedata [$c];
             }
             $i++;
          }
          fclose($file);

           dump($importData_arr);
          // Insert to MySQL database
          foreach($importData_arr as $importData){
           // var_dump($importData);
            $insertData = array(
                "EAN" =>$EANColumn,
               "Brand"=>$BrandColumn,
               "Name"=>$importData[2],
               "Size"=>$importData[3],
               "PCD"=>$importData[4],
               "Offset"=>$importData[5],
               "Bore"=>$importData[6],
               "Color"=>$importData[7],
               "Price"=>$importData[8],
               "Stock"=>$importData[9],
               "ImageURL"=>$importData[10]);
            RimsUpload::insertData($insertData);

          }

          Session::flash('message','Import Successful.');
        }else{
          Session::flash('message','File too large. File must be less than 2MB.');
        }

      }else{
         Session::flash('message','Invalid File Extension.');
      }

    }

    // Redirect to index
    // return redirect()->action("RimsUploadController@index", [$request]);
    return response()->redirectToAction('App\Http\Controllers\RimsUploadController@index', [$request]);
  }
```

But the real problem is that i do not want to map my columns like [0],[1],[2],[3]...
I would like to take them from the first row colum name : ["EAN"],["Brand"],["Name"],["Size"]...
So if EAN is column 1 or column 7, it wont make a difference, since it will detect it by name and not by row number.
So it will then be able to handle files with different column orders.

When trying to do this, i get the error :
`Undefined index: EAN on $EANColumn     = str_replace('’', '', $importData_arr["EAN"]);`

The whole point is to make an easy way to import data from suppliers through csv into mysql. then display it to the webshop site.

Comment: in your input_data does it not numeric index key? can you var_dump your $importData_arr ?

Comment: just create an Mapper-class where you may be able to map your rows to its related name   There you would be able also to apply some logic needed for your purposes ( myMapperClass->getValuesByBrandName(mybrandname) or whatever you want.

Comment: @Jerson array(0) { }

Comment: @ChristianFelix I am not sure what you mean by this, can you show me? Even if doing what i do, in a class. it will still return the error of undefined index

Comment: When you do not intend to apply special logic, use just this one:   $test = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']; $result = array_combine($test,$row); Now your array has an key associated to your value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your while loop, extract the field names from the first row of your csv:

```
$file = fopen($filepath,"r");
$keys = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ';');
```

Then, fetch the data lines and combine the `$keys` array with the data into an associative array:

```
$importData_arr = [];
while ($line = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ';')) {
    $data = array_combine($keys, $line);
    // Do something with the data
    $data['EAN'] = str_replace('’', '', $data['EAN']);
    $importData_arr[] = $data;
}
fclose($file);
```

You can now access all data fields by their name, independent of the order in the CSV:

```
foreach($importData_arr as $importData){
    echo $importData['EAN'];
}
```

As long as the field names stay intact, you don't have to change your import code when the field order or count changes.

Comment: @Michael Aggerholm: My first draft had a bug, fixed it!

Comment: why do i still need to define the offset "$importData_arr[0]" also. its a very nice solution, i added this. and everything seems fine, but i am getting the error : Undefined offset: 8. when adding 10 columns. i have double checked, nothing should be wrong, but it wont go higher than 7. any ideas?

Comment: @Michael Aggerholm: I skipped the `foreach` in my first example, so one had to specify an offset to access an element - see my updated answer with `foreach` loop like in your code.

Comment: @Michael Aggerholm: To address your second problem, just start debugging by `var_dump`'in `fgetcsv` line by line, there probably is some kind of error in your CSV file

Answer (score 0):

Here is some simple proposal how to map your data to an array with given keys.

```
while ($row = fgetcsv($fp, 100, ',')) {

      $columnName = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
      $myRow = array_combine($columnName,$row);
    ....
```